# How do I add a wwwroot directory to my WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

I am under the impression that the wwwroot directory is not just a normal folder. How do I add it to my project in Visual Studio 2019?

I have added the following to my Configure method in my Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Now I just need to add the wwwroot directory itself.
[image: My solution]

I am trying to do it for step 2 in the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.0

What is a wwwroot directory? Just a normal folder or something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a normal folder and call it `wwwroot`. That´s it.

Comment: @ I am geting can not add directory with special charecters.

Answer (score 4):

Add a new folder to the project and name it "wwwroot" the folder icon will automatically change.